# ModalPopupExtender setfocus issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

I'm using a Ajax `ModalPopupExtender` to show a popup panel. The panel has a `TextBox`. I want to `setfocus` to that `TextBox` while popup the panel. Is there is any method or mechanism to set the focus to the popup extender. I have tried many ways to achieve this, but failed. Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: yes, I got the solution, add the following Javascript function in <script> section `var clientid; function fnSetFocus(txtClientId) { clientid=txtClientId; setTimeout("fnFocus()",500); } function fnFocus() { eval("document.getElementById('"+clientid+"').focus()"); }` and add the following code in page_load function `btnAddNew.Attributes.Add("onclick", "fnSetFocus('" + tbTopicName.ClientID + "');");`

Answer (score 1):

Add the javascript below:

```
function pageLoad() {
    $find('modalPopupBehaviorID').add_shown(function () {
        $get("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").focus();
    });
}
```

Comment: where I need to call this Javascript function?

Comment: Nowhere. This is predefined function name that called on Application.Init and endRequest events.

Comment: This must work. The possible reason this may not work is if you don't change the "modalPopupBehaviorID" to your popup extender behavior ID or the "TextBox1" id to your textbox id.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tried many methods without any success, there is a good chance the focus code is executing a slight bit before the panel and text box exists.

setTimeout('document.getElementById("TextBox").focus();',1);

Answer (score 0):

On opening popup:

```
document.getElementById("TextBox").focus();
```

Hope this helps (and hope not to have been too obvious hehe)

Answer (score 0):

rkw 's answer among others helped me derive a convoluted fix. I had to use a timeout and a call to another function in order to properly place the focus in my modal textbox. Less convoluted solutions did not work for me. I believe, the addition of the setFocus() allowed for the proper execution queue to my desired end. ...hope this helps someone else. Like rkw suggested, only a millisecond was necessary to accomplish the task.

//markup

```
                    <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Add New Test" OnClick="btnShow_OnClick" OnClientClick="return modalAdjust()"  />
```

//javascript

```
  function setFocus() {
              try {
                  document.getElementById('<%= TextBox_TestDescription.ClientID %>').focus();
              } catch (e) {
                  alert(e);
              }
          }

          function modalAdjust() {
              try {
                  setTimeout("setFocus();", 1);
              }
              catch (e) {
                  alert(e);
              }
          }
```